# Provisioning Profile Breaking App Extension

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, entitlements

Hey so i have an app extension that i have built using xcode 7.1 on el capitan and i'm trying to get it to work on yosemite so it has backwards compatibility. However on yosemite no content gets displayed, console.app says that its been

```
 killed because com.team.example.exampleextension because its use of the com.devaloper.team-identifier entitlement is not allowed.
```

I have tried reseting provisioning profiles and googled around but its just not working.

im also getting this in console.app

```
"app" checked in with appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be read and validated by appleeventsd, and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by name, bundle id, or signature. Install the application in /Applications/ or some other world readable location to resolve this issue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because the device i was using was not on my devices list under the dev portal! Didnt know this was so important haha